# Discrete random variable definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two different definitions defining discrete random variables (wikipedia and a textbook)

> Def 1 : $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is discrete if it's image is countable

> Def 2: $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is discrete if $ \exists E \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ countable such that $P(X^{-1} (E)) = 1$

Now, 1 $\implies$ 2 is clear to me.

However I keep coming to the conclusion that the other direction doesn't necessarily have to hold. My reasoning is $X$ could still have an uncountable image with a countable subset $E$ as above, since there could be a bunch of events in the sample space corresponding to zero probability essentially.

What I mean is it could be that $P((X^{-1}(E)^\complement)=0$ and from the fact that for some set $A \subseteq \Omega$, $P(A) = 1$ does not imply $A = \Omega$, in general.

I know that this doesn't really matter and won't affect any theorems later on but I just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something crucial since I'm fairly new to probability.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The two definitions are not much different from each other. As you also say, as per Def 2 also, even if $X$ assumes uncountably many points, it doesn't really matter as only countably many points only have positive mass. However, in advanced level probability courses, you don't have discrete and continuous random variables; you have only absolutely continuous and singular random variables.